# Postgres Function exists in a particular schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I have  postgres DB which has multiple schemas, is there a way (query) which I can run to figure out if a function exists in a specific schema or in other words print a list of schema names under which a given function exists.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/infoschema-routines.html

Comment: `\df *.funcname` in `psql`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can adapt following query:

```
select routine_name, routine_schema 
from information_schema.routines 
where routine_name='myfunction' 
and routine_type='FUNCTION';
```